# AVCaptureDeviceFormat 1080p 60 fps Autofocus issue

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, autofocus, avcapturedevice

I noticed that AVCaptureDeviceFormat 1080p 60 fps on iPhone 6s does not supports focus pixels, so in low light conditions the camera continues to autofocus when moved. This creates an issue with video recording as focus hunting is an issue. However the native camera app works wonderfully with 1080p 60 fps setting without any focus hunting in the same scenario. How does native camera achieve it? I tried locking focus before recording and also tried setting device.smoothAutoFocusEnabled to YES but the results are still not good enough like native Camera app. Any ideas ?

Comment: Having a similar issue and wondering how the camera app accomplishes this but no matter what I try I am getting the "focus hunting" problem. Did you find a solution? I think the issue is there with 30fps but certainly becomes more noticeable at 60fps.

Comment: So far nothing :(

Comment: Can you also post the complete that that you have sued @kanso

Answer (score 0):

Back camera supports 2 different autofocus systems:

- AVCaptureAutoFocusSystemContrastDetection - Indicates that autofocus is achieved by contrast detection. Contrast detection performs a focus scan to find the optimal position.
- AVCaptureAutoFocusSystemPhaseDetection - Indicates that autofocus is achieved by phase detection. Phase detection has the ability to achieve focus in many cases without a focus scan. Phase detection autofocus is typically less visually intrusive than contrast detection autofocus.

When you choose the format from the list of supported formats, make sure you use format where autofocus system is **AVCaptureAutoFocusSystemPhaseDetection**.